# Adding key switch to a PC.

Tags: switches, switching, toggle-switch

So, I'm making a custom PC case for myself. I want to add a simple on/off key switch (like all of the bikes have), only on ignition, start + restart button should work.

Here problem is that, I bought a ignition switch of some motor bike which has on/off as I wanted,  but when switch is ON, circuit opens, when it is OFF, circuit closes. (that's how bikes work, when switch is OFF, earthing doesn't allow bike to start. Similarly when switch is ON, earthing breaks and bike can be started.

I want to use this key switch in my PC. Are there any electronic parts that I can use in my case?

Such as if switch is OFF (here close)  but PC shouldn't start and when switch is ON (open) , PC starts?

Simple on/off key switch is not available at my place. I've searched every single store.

Here's a video about the switch I want. 
https://youtu.be/fUeIVqdZyy4

Comment: Use an electromechanical relay......

Comment: Whoa. That's what I was looking for. Is cutout equipment to relay?

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) motherboards are built in such a way that they require a momentary connection to start. The board is under power, and a controller is checking if the power button is pushed (and released again). When it senses this, it will power on the system. If it senses a new push, it will tell this to the processor in some manner, so the operating system can decide how to deal with it.

This means that you can't use a classic "on/off" switch can be used on it's own.

However, as the video demonstrates, nothing stops you from using it in series with the original switch. In your case, you could use an inverter in series with the original switch, with the inverter connected to the switch.

You would need to find the required voltage rails on your motherboard to do this, and watch out since motherboards can be fragile, and mistakes can lead to damage to attached components such as the CPU, PCIe cards, ...